# ExoPlayer version 2.18.1

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Android I have use multiple video to play using ExoPlayer in adapter, that adapter using fragment.
The issue is move to another activity or fragment is video is  still playing background adapter how to solve it Kotlin, ExoPlayer version 2.18.1

I want to move another fragment or activity video is don't playing.

Comment: You should add more detail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.